# Is travelling to one country or two countries enough travel history to support my Canada visa application?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada, international-travel, visitor

A travel history is needed for my Canada visitor application. Is travelling to visa-free countries once or twice or the same neighbouring countries multiple times enough to support my travel history for a Canada visitor visa application?

Comment: Typically a history of travel to equivalent countries eg Schengen, USA, UK is likely to be helpful. What do you mean by *neighbouring countries*?

Comment: Having travelled to other countries is **not** a requirement for any visa application. It may help tip the scale in your favour if your application isn’t very strong, but it will be a lot more effective if you have visits to countries with the same approximate cost of living/average revenue as the intended destination (e.g. in the case of Canada: Schengen countries, UK, Ireland, USA, Australia, New Zealand, Japan, etc.). Anything is probably better than nothing, but it may not count for much.

Comment: What is the reason for your visit to Canada?  Travel history will be more important for tourism than (say) an employer-sponsored business trip.

Comment: One of your most recent questions about visiting Canada states you were refused because they were not satisfied about your intention to leave at the end of your stay https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/180639/what-does-canada-immigration-officer-mean-by-im-not-satisfied-that-you-will-le A history of travelling visa-free a couple of times to neighbouring countries probably won’t be enough to overcome that unless eg your ties to your home country are stronger than when you previously applied

Comment: Voting to close as this as opinion-based. We are not consular officers, therefore anything provided as an answer is merely an opinion